# how to disable ionic form field depending on other form field values?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

there is one ion select

```
 <ion-select interface="popover" formControlName="window_exists"  (ionChange)="openWindow()" type="text">
          <ion-option value="Y">Yes</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="N">No</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
```

i want to disable ion input if ion-option value is "NO"

```
 <ion-input   type="number" min="0" formControlName="ml_window_no" required clearInput></ion-input>
```

please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, need to pass $event as a parameter,

```
<ion-select interface="popover" formControlName="window_exists"  (ionChange)="openWindow($event)" type="text">
  <ion-option value="Y">Yes</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="N">No</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And, add a disabled property like this,

```
<ion-input disabled="{{isDisabled}}" type="number" min="0" formControlName="ml_window_no" required clearInput></ion-input>
```

Now, you have to add this code in .ts file,

```
isDisabled:boolean = false;

openWindow(event){
     console.log('event',event);
     if (event == 'N') {
       console.log('no');
       this.isDisabled = true;
     }else{
       console.log('yes');
       this.isDisabled = false;
     }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again AddWeb, :)

Comment: can you please check out this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292597/how-to-copy-image-in-ionic-app-local-folder-from-a-specific-path